# Please help me understand effect on file permissions on combining umask an ACL and Samba create mask

Tags: 20.04, permissions, samba, acl, umask

I set up an ACL in /media/4TB1

My intention is to enforce these two points:

1. All sub-directories of /media/4TB1 will have permissions: `drwxrwxr-x` i.e: chmod 775
2. All files will get permissions: `-rw-rw-r--` i.e: chmod 664

This is the ACL:
`sudo setfacl -dRm u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x /media/4TB1`

Already I think my understanding is wrong.
Does my ACL do anything to enforce permissions on files? Or does it affect directories only?

In my Ubuntu 20.04 the umask is `0022`.

I also have a Samba share that points to /media/4TB1
When I have this line in the share definition `create mask = 664`

Files are created like this: `-rw-rw-r--`

When I have this line in the share definition `create mask = 777`

Files are created like this: `-rwxrw-r--`

But I was expecting files to have these permissions: 777-022 = 755 `[-rwxr-xr-x]`

Can someone explain that please?

Also, does Samba "Create Mask" over-ride an ACL?

I read elsewhere that "create mask" is an AND mask and "force create mode" is an OR mask but I'm totally confused now.

Any help much appreciated!

Flex

Comment: 2 settings are important: "obey pam restrictions" needs to be `off` otherwise pam might interfer with your other "masks" and if you want to use the acl settings set `inherit acls = yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the ACL part of your question since I've managed to exist this long without using them and I don't know how they interact with the basic samba file creation process.

A newly created samba file has permissions of 766 not 666 because of another parameter ( map archive ) that enables the execute bit on the owner of the file. The binary representation of that is 111 110 110.

A "create mask" value of 664 is converted to the binary format then a logical AND is performed on 766. In a logical AND if both numbers are 1 the answer is 1. If one number is 0 the answer is 0. So what we have is:

> 111 110 110 > 766
>
> 110 110 100 > 664
>
> ===========
>
> 110 110 100 which is octal 664

Let's do the same thing with a create mask of 777:

> 111 110 110 > 766
>
> 111 111 111 > 777
>
> ===========
>
> 111 110 110 which is octal 766

Instead of a "create mask" let's use a "force create mode = 0777". Here the "mode" does a logical OR to the original permissions. In a logical OR if any number is 1 the answer is 1:

> 111 110 110 > 766
>
> 111 111 111 > 777
>
> ===========
>
> 111 111 111 which is octal 777

Note: the default masking in samba is set to 744:

> 111 110 110 which is 766
>
> 111 100 100 which is 744
>
> ===========
>
> 111 100 100 which is 744

Which is why without any other parameters in smb.conf newly created files will have execute set for owner.

I've created a test share and went through the different settings to illustrate the result:

```
tester@vub2004:~$ ls -l Shared
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Apr 27 12:28 fromLinux-cm0664.txt
-rwxrw-rw- 1 tester tester 0 Apr 27 12:31 fromLinux-cm0777.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tester tester 0 Apr 27 12:37 fromLinux-fcm0777.txt
-rwxr--r-- 1 tester tester 0 Apr 27 12:25 fromLinux-default.txt
```

Comment: `A newly created samba file has permissions of 766 not 666 because of another parameter ( map archive ) that enables the execute bit on the owner of the file.` THANK YOU for this!! I was literally just about to ask this very question! So now I understand why the result of bitwise AND-ing the Samba default `create mask` of `rwx-r--r--` (744) with the permissions of a file that Samba created (766) gives `rwxr--r--`. So to get the `normal` behavior I could use `map archive = no` in my smb.conf. Samba must ignore umask and ACLs entirely? If anyone could confirm this I would be grateful.

Comment: It seems that YES Samba does ignore ACLs and umask in Linux. [This link](http://www.bodenzord.com/archives/53) states: *"To put it bluntly, Samba ignores the UMASK setting in the Linux environment. Instead, it provides its own equivalent parameter."* and regarding the Samba setting `inherit acls (S)` the online documentation for [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) states: *"This parameter can be used to ensure that if default acls exist on parent directories.... The default behavior is to use the unix mode specified when creating the directory. "*